# Is it a norm to use class or id for header and section in html

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML and CSS and as I was watching beginner tutorials on Youtube, I faced some confusion concerning if it is ok to use class or id for header and section. Since header and section should not be used as a wrapper and have to be used for document outline purposes only. Bearning in mind this fact why we use class or id with header and section to give style to both. For example:

```
<header class="showcase">
<header>
```

and

```
<section class="about">
<section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly acceptable to put a `class` or and `id` on either `<header>` or `<section>` since it's valid HTML to use up to multiple of them - it makes it easier to target them.

With that said, an `id` should always be unique per page. For example, never use the same `id` more than once in the entire page... that's what classes are used for.

It's also perfectly acceptable to style the `<header>` and `<section>` tags directly. It's ultimately your choice... To reinforce this concept, even browsers will have slightly different default styles for those elements. E.g. Opera may have slightly different `default` CSS to what Chrome might have.

Comment: thank you Ashley for your attention, as you know, header and section are used to define outline of a document and why we use class or id to style header and section. Shouldn't div be used for styling purposes? For example <header><div class="showcase"></div><header>.

Comment: @Mirich It's as I explained in the last paragraph... it's ultimately your choice in how you want to do it. To not have a `<div>` within either `<section>` or `<header>` and to style them directly is perfectly acceptable. Just because a particular element is an 'outline', this doesn't mean it can't have custom CSS applied to it.

Answer (score 1):

I use class and id all the time for ALL HTML elements. One thing to pay attention is for the id to be unique.

Comment: yes yes I know when to use id and class. The question is if we want to give style to header or section then why don't we use div. For example <header><div class="showcase"></div><header>?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you can right css for header and footer without adding class, because we will have only one header and footer in one application. But for section you can use class because there can be multiple sections on a page. Common styles for section you can write using section only and for other styles you can use class.

If you have more doubts, let m know.

Comment: You can have several <header> elements in one document. [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_header.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I does not matter at all, but personally I like to use class elements for things that I'm gonging to use multiple times (Example text sizes or colours) and ID's for things like logo's that will only appear once on the page.

Also, I like to use ID's for JavaScript and Classes for CSS.

But it totally does not matter at all, so use with whatever you feel convertible with!

Answer (score 0):

it is generally a good practice to specify classes for sections in HTML. This can help maintain a cohesive design and make it easier to update the styling of multiple sections at once by modifying the CSS rules for that class.